# Python(3.6)-How can I create a demo program that will create an object from the VotingMachine class I have created?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have so far. I have created this class:

```
class VotingMachine :
    def __init__(self):
        self._voteCount = 0
        self._totalVote = 0

    def DemVote(self, vote):
        self._voteDemCount = self._voteDemCount + 1
        self._totalDemVote = self._totalDemVote + vote

    def RepVote(self, vote):
        self._voteRepCount = self._voteRepCount + 1
        self._totalRepVote = self._totalRepVote + 1

    def getDemTally(self):
        return self._totalDemVote

    def getRepTally(self):
        return self._totalRepVote

    def clear(self):
        self._voteCount = 0
        self._totalVote = 0
```

and this is what I have so far for the demo program.

```
from votingmachine import VotingMachine

print("Presidential Election")
print("---------------------")
print("R -- Republican")
print("D -- Democrat")
print("X -- Stop")

userInput = input("Enter your vote (R/D/X): ")
```

My instructions for this are as follows-

Create a voteDemo program that will create one object from the VotingMachine class. The voteDemo program should display a menu, allow the user to enter multiple votes until an X is entered, then show the tally of the Democratic and Republican votes, and also show which candidate won the election.
Make sure to consider that the election could end in a tie.

I know I have probably missed something really simple, but I am a complete beginner at this and do not understand how to go about calling the methods to be able to display a menu, etc. I would really appreciate it if someone would take the time to explain what I need to do to finish this up.

Comment: A style note: it's customary to name classes `LikeThis`, but name methods `like_this`, thus `dem_vote`. It's also customary to name methods by verbs, e.g. `get_dem_vote_tally`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete this assignment you need to know how to:

- Compare strings

  ```
  first = "a"
  second = "b"
  third = "b"
  print(first == second) # prints False
  print(second == third) # prints True
  ```
- Use a while loop. For example:

  ```
  looping = True
  while looping:
      userInput = input("Press X to leave the loop")
      if userInput == "X":
          looping = False
  print("Left the while loop")
  ```
- Call methods

  ```
  class Animal:
      def __init__(self):
          print("Creating animal")

      def make_sound(self, sound):
          print("Making a sound...")
          print(sound)

  # Create an instance of the Animal class.
  animal = Animal()
  # Call a method. The self parameter implicitly refers to the instance, animal.
  animal.make_sound("meow")
  ```

You can solve the problem by combining these tools.

Comment: Thank you so much! That explanation really cleared up the `self` parameter for me. My textbook is not very clear on many things and getting answers such as this helps me to understand Python much better!!

Comment: Sure thing, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple loop to do what you want:

```
userInput = ''
voting_machine = VotingMachine()

while userInput != 'x':
    userInput = input("Enter your vote (R/D/X): ").lower()

    if userInput == 'd':
        pass
    elif userInput == 'r':
        pass
    elif userInput == 'x':
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong input! Try again!")

print(voting_machine.getDemTally())
print(voting_machine.getRepTally())
print("Bye!")
```

Actually, the definition of your class, has some **errors**, you didn't define attributes like _voteRepCount before using them.

Comment: Consider `userInput = input(...).lower()` once, not in every condition.

Comment: @9000, good point, already changed it, many thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: When you say I didn't define attributes like _voteRepCount, does that mean they need to be initialized in the `__init__` function?

Comment: @MenglongLi  great! Appreciate the help so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can *instantiate* (create a instance of) a class in python with the following code: `machine = VotingMachine()`.

You might also want to check the code in your `DemVote` and `RepVote` methods. `self._voteDemCount` and `self._voteRepCount` need to be initialized in your `__init__` function and the methods do different things with `vote`.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a voting machine: `machine = VotingMachine()`.

Then run a loop, asking for a vote, feeding it to the machine, and showing the tallies in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
class VotingMachine:
    def __init__(self):
        self._totalVote = 0
        self._voteDemCount = 0
        self._voteRepCount = 0

    def demVote(self):
        self._voteDemCount += 1
        self._totalVote += 1

    def repVote(self):
        self._voteRepCount += 1
        self._totalVote += 1

    def getDemTally(self):
        return self._voteDemCount

    def getRepTally(self):
        return self._voteRepCount

    def getTally(self):
        return self._totalVote

    def clear(self):
        self._totalVote = 0
```

voteDemo

```
from VotingMachine import *
election = VotingMachine()
print("Presidential Election")

vote = ''
while vote != 'X':
    print("---------------------")
    print("R -- Republican")
    print("D -- Democrat")
    print("X -- Stop")
    vote = input("Enter your vote (R/D/X): ")

    if vote == 'X':
        print("Tally votes: "+str(election.getTally()))
        if election.getDemTally() > election.getRepTally():
            print("Democrat WIN")
        elif election.getDemTally() < election.getRepTally():
            print("Republican WIN")
        else:
            print("Draw")
        print("(D:"+str(election.getDemTally())+" , R:"+str(election.getRepTally())+")")
    elif vote == 'R':
        election.repVote()
    elif vote == 'D':
        election.demVote()
    else:
        print("Vote invalid!")
```